# change a string in my xml code non programatically

Tags: android, xml, string

Hello I am wondering if there is a way to change a string value  in my xml code without touching the .java file

e.g.
in case i have in the strings.xml

```
<string name="title"> This is my title</string>
```

If I can change inside my main.xml file
The string to have the value: This is **my** title

meaning to have the third word of my string on bold

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `strings.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title"> This is <b>my</b> title</string> 
</resources>
```

Comment: Actually I can not really understand what you mean

Comment: I just tried to make the simple things hard for no reason. :-)

Comment: whaterver dude. What's really matter is that you fix your issue.